# Assigning String to Double.... Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUVTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Picker View (I call them spinners) with two components which happen to equate to £ and pence values... The data source for each is 0 to 99 so that a user can select any value from £0.00 to £99.99

I have the following bit of code with a prepareForSegue function

```
//need to find out what the spinner is set to
var firstComponent = pickerData[0][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
firstComponent = firstComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "£ ", withString: "" )

var secondComponent = pickerData[1][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
secondComponent = secondComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "  .", withString: "" )

let amountAsString = firstComponent + "." + secondComponent
Data.sharedData.fuelAmount = Double(amountAsString)!
```

Data.sharedData.fuleAmount is declared as a Double in my singleton class...

```
import Foundation

class Data: NSObject {

    static let sharedData = Data()

    var startMileage: String!
    var previousMileage: String!
    var startLocation:String!
    var endLocation:String!

    var didFillUp: Bool!

    var previousFuelMileage: String!
    var fuelFillMileage: String!
    var fuelAmount: Double!

    var sender: String!

}
```

When run the program breaks at the last of these lines with the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUVTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

As I'm new to Xcode and Swift I'm struggling trying to debug and find the cause... Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you print out `amountAsString` what does it show? On a sidenote, you should try to avoid implicitly unwrapping whenever possible to prevent errors like these. And finally, I wouldn't recommend using `Double` for currencies. Better to work with `NSDecimalNumber` or keep the decimals as an `Int`. It'll save you a lot of problems / headaches later on.

Comment: @Eendje amountAsString values have all looked good... sample values I have are "32.45", "11.04", "5.00", "64.02", "9.55" etc... I'll see if changing to NSDecimalNumber helps...

Comment: Changing to NSDecimalNumber did not help. I got around the problem by using @Eendje second suggestion and keep the fuel amount as Int... I'm actually storing the amount as two Int(s) one for the Pound value and another for Pence value.

Comment: Changing to NSDecimalNumber wasn't suppose to help. It's just when you're dealing with currency, you shouldn't use float or double. Because, if you try `print((9.49 * 0.1) == 0.949)` it prints: `false`.

Comment: @Eendje - understand... all done now works using int values... my app is quite simple... no math involved it just stores mileage and fuel which can then be output so it can be submitted in a company mileage log